# snakemake wrapper Gatk/Mutect2

Tags: snakemake

In the Snakemake Wrapper documentation

```
rule mutect2_bam:
    input:
        fasta="genome/genome.fasta",
        map="mapped/{sample}.bam",
    output:
        vcf="variant_bam/{sample}.vcf",
        bam="variant_bam/{sample}.bam",
    message:
        "Testing Mutect2 with {wildcards.sample}"
    threads: 1
    resources:
        mem_mb=1024,
    log:
        "logs/mutect_{sample}.log",
    wrapper:
        "v1.10.0/bio/gatk/mutect"
```

Is just only one input bam file, but if I have to use two bam files. What should I do?

Comment: I reiterate a previous comment/question of mine: What's the point of wrappers? Just write the mutect command in the shell directive and be explicit about what input, output, and params you need.